# Scriptdb to BigQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Currently, I have an application that writes from google Apps Script to ScriptDB. Because it is being removed shortly, is there a way to transfer ScriptDB to bigQuery, and then have the application write to BigQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: have you read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/script-db  ?

Comment: yes. It does not really answer my question. I still need to have an application that writes to BigQuery on a daily basis

Comment: there are many examples in the right margin of this page undre "related"... they show examples of data exchange with bigquery.

Comment: among others :https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

Comment: There's lots of examples of BigQuery and AppsScript: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bigquery_tutorial and https://gist.github.com/soundTricker/2917197 and http://ctrlq.org/code/19857-upload-csv-files-to-bigquery